# sqlite3 cannot be bundle in windows rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, sqlite

current directory:
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20190227-5688-2rzd4d.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3

C:\Users\User\blog>gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
```

C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20190227-8976-1h69dwp.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for -ldl... no
checking for dlopen()... no
missing function dlopen
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --with-dllib
        --without-dllib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

C:\Users\User\blog>gem unlink sqlite
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command unlink

C:\Users\User\blog>gem install sqlite3 --universal
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --universal

C:\Users\User\blog>gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.8.8.1
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3-3.26.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
Building native extensions with: '--with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.8.8.1'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
```

C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20190227-13444-5xb02v.rb extconf.rb --with-sqlite3-dir\=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.8.8.1
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for -ldl... no
checking for dlopen()... no
missing function dlopen
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --with-dllib
        --without-dllib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

Comment: Can you be precise, this information seems to be overkilling the question!!

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: rails 5.2.2, ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: ok @CharlesSkariah,      Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options. (makefile for sqlite3)

Comment: @bottles Can you specify a lower version of sqlite3 in the gemfile instead of 1.4.0.Anything around the 1.3 version will be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the known issue for Rails 5.2.2 ([issue #35153](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35153)).

To sort out this change version of `sqlite`:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
```

Comment: wow thanks, It worked great but now when i run Rails server, its giving me  "You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile."..   though im using Bundler version 2.0.1(i have tried bundler update too)

Comment: Remove your lockfile and retry

Comment: did and getting this:   check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated bundler 2.0.1, but your Gemfile requires bundler 1.17.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)